# What is the standard way in C++11 to access the pointer to element n in a std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, std

What is the standard way in C++11 to access the pointer to element n in a `std::vector`?

```
vec.data() + n
```

or

```
&vec[n]
```

comes to mind.

Comment: Are you referring to [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The standard way" is not existent, both ways in your questions work fine and there are no performance-related issues here. But there might be additional circumstances to take into account: error handling, static analysis warnings, possibly overloaded `operator &`, the ability to substitute `std::vector` with a different type.

1. Static analysis. When you use the first version, `clang-tidy` throws

   > ```
   > warning: do not use pointer arithmetic [cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-pointer-arithmetic]
   > vec.data() + 1;
   >            ^
   > ```

   at you (given that this particular check is enabled of course). Not the most severe issue, but for completeness, this warning doesn't occur when you use the second version.
2. Substituting `std::vector` with another continuous container type or if you write a template (you basically want to keep the requirements on your type as small as possible). Then,

   ```
   auto *ptr = vec.data() + n;
   ```

   requires the `.data()` member function to be present and do what you expect it to do. Example: Llvm's `SmallVector` template (optimized for fewer allocations) doesn't have `data()` but it does have `operator []`. I would argue that due to this reason,

   ```
   auto *ptr = &vec[n];
   ```

   is preferable. Admittedly, another vector type could equally well overload `operator()(...)` instead of `[]` (or not have an overloaded operator at all), but this is probably easier to fix across some functions than the `.data() + n` approach.

Let me hence therefore consider the second version for the following two issues.

2. Error handling: When you need to check whether the vector has at least a size of `n + 1`:

   ```
   auto *ptr = vec.size() > n ? &vec[n] : nullptr;
   ```

   needs to be compared to the check baked into `std::vector` itself:

   ```
   try {
       auto *ptr = &vec.at(n);
        // Do stuff with ptr
   } catch (const std::out_of_range&) { /* ... */ }
   ```

   Which one is better here heavily depends on project- and context-specific circumstances (are exceptions enabled, is the size of the vector a precondition of some scope etc.), so it's impossible to generally select one. It's good though to know about these options.
3. Overloaded `operator &`. In code that's supposed to be reused in a different context, it doesn't hurt to do

   ```
   auto *ptr = std::addressof(vec[n]);
   ```

   as this plays nicely with evil overloads of this operator.

Combining the above scenarios, choose an approach that fits best for the specific situation.

Comment: This elaborate answer renders other answers superfluous. +1.

Comment: Note: using `&vec[n]` to get the pointer to `end()` element is undefined behavior. For that one needs to use `vec.data()+n`.